# Get deepest level children from nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, nested

I have 2 types of a objects, a `group`, and an `item`. A group can have `children` which is either an `array of groups` or an `array of items`.

I've ended up with a series of nested groups (which can be infinite levels deep) and I need to retrieve all the items, no matter how many levels deep, with only a group to work with.

Is there a way to retrieve all the items from the top-level group in the following data structure?

```
{
  type: 'group',
  children: [
    {
      type: 'group',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}, {type:'item'}, {type:'item'}]
        },
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}, {type:'item'}, {type:'item'}]
        },
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}, {type:'item'}, {type:'item'}]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'group',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}]
        },
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}]
        },
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'group',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}, {type:'item'}]
        },
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}, {type:'item'}]
        },
        {
          type: 'group',
          children: [{type:'item'}, {type:'item'}]
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: your data structure is not valid. arrays have no property in a literal.

Comment: if you make it correct then use recursion tech to cater this.

Comment: As you won't have property labels available to you in an actual array, how will you differentiate between an array of group objects and array of item objects? If you can show an example of an actual array and include the group and item object definitions this might be easier.

Comment: btw, what qualifies a deep node? or would you like to get all nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an iterative with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and recursive with calling `iter` again, approach.

```js
var data = { children: [{ children: [{ children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }] }, { children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }] }, { children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }] }] }, { children: [{ children: [{ name: 'item1' }] }, { children: [{ name: 'item1' }] }, { children: [{ name: 'item1' }] }] }, { children: [{ children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }] }, { children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }] }, { children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }] }] }] },
    children = [data].reduce(function iter(r, a) {
        if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            return a.children.reduce(iter, r);
        }
        r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(children);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with recursion.

```js
var data = {
  children: [
    {
      children: [
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }]
        },
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }]
        },
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      children: [
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }]
        },
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }]
        },
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      children: [
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }]
        },
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }]
        },
        {
          children: [{ name: 'item1' }, { name: 'item2' }, { name: 'item3' }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


function getAllChildren(group, children) {
  children = children || [];
  if(group && Array.isArray(group.children)) {
    group.children.forEach(function(child) { 
      getAllChildren(child, children)
    });
  }
  else {
    children.push(group);
  }
  return children;
}

console.log(getAllChildren(data));
```